# How do I make a login user check using a class in PHP?

Tags: php, session

Im making a login system using PHP classes. Im using code from a previous login form that worked without the use of classes, but now im using classes, it only partially works.

The output says that a session is being started, which is good, but the user doesnt get redirected to the right page. It stays on the same page.

This is my login form code:

```
public function loginAccount() {
        include ('../includes/config.inc.php');

        if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_start();
        } else {
            session_destroy();  
            session_start(); 
        }

        if(isset($_POST["login"]))  
        { 
            if(empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["wachtwoord"]))  
            {  
                $message = '<label>Vul alle velden in</label>';  
            }  
            else   
            {  
                $query = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE email = :email AND wachtwoord = :wachtwoord";  
                $statement = $con->prepare($query);  
                $statement->execute(  
                    array(  
                        'email'     =>     htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]),  
                        'wachtwoord'     =>     htmlspecialchars($_POST["wachtwoord"])  
                    )  
                );  




                $count = $statement->rowCount();  
                if($count > 0)  
                {  

                    $_SESSION["email"] = $_POST["wachtwoord"]; 
                    $username = $_SESSION["email"];
                    $query = "SELECT rol, voornaam, achternaam FROM account WHERE email = :email";

                    $stm = $con->prepare($query);
                    $stm->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $stm->execute();
                    $result = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

                    foreach ($result as $pers) {
                        $rol = $pers->rol; 
                        $voornaam = $pers->voornaam; 
                        $achternaam = $pers->achternaam; 
                        $_SESSION["voornaam"] = $voornaam; 
                        $_SESSION["achternaam"] = $achternaam; 
                        $_SESSION["rol"] = $rol;
                        if($_SESSION["rol"] == 'Admin') {
                            header("location:index.php");  
                        } else 
                        if($_SESSION["rol"] == 'Gebruiker') {
                            header("location:../index.php");  
                        } else {
                            header("location:login.php");  
                        }
                    } 

                }  
                else  
                {  
                   $message = '<label>Verkeerde Gegevens</label>';  
                }  
            }  
        }
    }
```

This code is inside a class called Account.
This is the form code of the login page:

```
<?php
$accounts = new Account();
$accounts->loginAccount();

?>
```

What could be the issue here?

While testing i found out that the issue lies in the

```
foreach ($result as $pers) {
                        $rol = $pers->rol; 
                        $voornaam = $pers->voornaam; 
                        $achternaam = $pers->achternaam; 
                        $_SESSION["voornaam"] = $voornaam; 
                        $_SESSION["achternaam"] = $achternaam; 
                        $_SESSION["rol"] = $rol;
                        if($_SESSION["rol"] == 'Admin') {
                            header("location:index.php");  
                        } else 
                        if($_SESSION["rol"] == 'Gebruiker') {
                            header("location:../index.php");  
                        } else {
                            header("location:login.php");  
                        }
                    }
```

section of the code.

Comment: _“While testing i found out that the issue lies in the […] section of the code.”_ - how did you figure that? What else have you done so far to try and debug this? Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled?

Comment: try to echo $pers->rol and die();. lets check what is coming.

Answer (score -1):

1) Try to use this syntax:
header("Location: index.php");
instead of this:
header("location:index.php");
(The first letter is upper case and space after `:`)

2) Make sure you don't have any output before calling the `header` function. If you have some output, the function will not work

Comment: nothing within the foreach works. Anywhere else it works